# How do I set custom spaces in tabular so that multicolumn behaves well?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multicolumn, alignment

The following code

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \raggedright
  \begin{tabular}{l@{ }l@{ }l@{ }l}
    super:     & foo                            & bar & baz\\
    cali:      & \multicolumn{2}{@{ }l}{foobar}       & baz\\
    fragili:   & foo                            & bar & baz\\
    stichespi: & foo                            & bar & baz\\
    ralidoso:  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{foobar}           & baz\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

generates this

[image]

where it's clear that the `@{ }` in the `\multicolumn` at the 2nd row had an effect, as it's different from  the spacing at the 5th row.

On the other hand, had I set those custom spaces to zero, i.e. `@{}`,

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \raggedright
  \begin{tabular}{l@{}l@{}l@{}l}
    super:     & foo                            & bar & baz\\
    cali:      & \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{foobar}        & baz\\
    fragili:   & foo                            & bar & baz\\
    stichespi: & foo                            & bar & baz\\
    ralidoso:  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{foobar}           & baz\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

then I'd have got a consistent spacing, though insufficient:

[image]

Comment: What about for example `\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}` before table? Is this an option? Sory, it is not (at least to me) entirely clear what you after.

Comment: `\tabcolsep` is not the issue here

Comment: @Zarko, I want the cells of the second column to be left aligned, even those which are actually multicolumn cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

except for the first column `@{}` (and `|`) are considered part of the *preceding* column,  so in `\multicolumn` you almost always should use `l@{ }` not `@{ }l`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \raggedright
  \begin{tabular}{l@{ }l@{ }l@{ }l}
    super:     & foo                            & bar & baz\\
    cali:      & \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{ }}{foobar}       & baz\\
    fragili:   & foo                            & bar & baz\\
    stichespi: & foo                            & bar & baz\\
    ralidoso:  & \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{ }}{foobar}           & baz\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand why that should solve the issue. I want to set to 1 space the space between the first column and the second, even if the cell is a multicolumn. That should mean, based on your explanation, I need `@{ }l`, not `l@{ }`. Anyway, I've tried, and I don't get the correct result.

Comment: @Enlico sorry first version only had half the story, see update

Comment: Thanks, it works. By changing `l@{ }l@{ }l@{ }l` to `l@{x}l@{y}l@{z}l}` and `@{}l@{ }` to `@{w}l@{z}`, I understand that the multicolumn is followed by the space following its own `l` (`z`) and preceded by the sum of 2 spaces the one preceding its own `l` (`w`) and the one that would belong to the first of its columns, as determined by the table (`x`).